# emulating line space of displayed multiline math in non-math mode

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing, inline

I want to use displayed style for inline math, i.e. `\everymath{\displaystyle}`, but the line space is too tight when, for example, fractions appear in consecutive lines.

I want to change this via `\lineskiplimit` and `\lineskip`, like this

```
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{\lineskiplimit}
```

then I find this setting affects line space in displayed multiline, such as

```
\begin{align*}
  \frac{2}{2} &= \frac{2}{2} \\
              &= 1 \\
              &= 1 \\
              &= \frac{2}{2} \\
              &= 1 \\
              &= \frac{2}{2} \\
              &= \frac{2}{2} \\
              &= 1
\end{align*}
```

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

So I have 2 questions:

1. how to avoid affecting line space in multiline displayed math
2. how to replace `5pt` by minimal line skip in multiline displayed math, eg. the vertical space between two `\frac{2}{2}` in the first image

Comment: using `\lineskip`  to space lines in a paragraph should be a last resort, it by design produces irregular line spacing. It is much better to increase `\baselinskip` so that `\lineskip` is never used.

Answer (score 1):

After reading some books on plain TeX, I understand that when entering displayed math mode, there is a command `\openup`, which increases `\baselineskip`, `\lineskip`, `\lineskiplimit` by one `\jot`, which is 3pt by default. So I'm going to use the following code to emulating the behavior

```
\addtolength{\lineskiplimit}{\jot}
\addtolength{\lineskip}{\jot}
\everydisplay{\normalbaselines}
```

If there are something besides display math mode also changes `\lineskiplimit` and `\lineskip`, it will cause unexpected result.